# area of $r = \theta$ bounded by two lines

Tags: definite-integrals, area

Unsure how to complete the question where it states I need to find the area bounded for $r = \theta$ for ($\theta\ge0$ ). Bounded by $\pi/3$ and $\pi/6$. would I just integrate and substitute to get $\sec^3(x) \ dx$ then set the limits to $\pi/3$ and $\pi/6$?

Comment: sorry i tryed to format this but did not succeed

Comment: Just put dollar signs around each formula. Oh, and BTW, "I" is written as uppercase letter.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to calculate the area in the polar plane bounded by the curve $r = \theta$ and the lines $\theta = \pi/6$, $\theta = \pi/3$.

The best way I know to do this is to use a transformation formula. Let $f$ be the transformation from standard to polar coordinates:
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, \quad f(r,\theta) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta).$$
Then let $U = \{ (r,\theta) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \le r \le \theta, \, \pi/6 \le \theta \le \pi \}$, so we want the area of $f(U)$. By the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables), we have that

$$\text{Area $f(U)$} = \int_{f(U)} 1 = \int_U \left | \det (Df) \right | = \int_U r = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \int_0^\theta r \, dr \, d\theta = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \theta^2/2 \, d \theta,$$
which is quite simple to evaluate as $((\pi/3)^3-(\pi/6)^3)/6$.